# How to detect screenshots in Ubuntu?

Tags: security, screenshot

Apart from monitoring keystrokes for `Print Screen`, is there a way for a tool or software running in Ubuntu (whatever the desktop) to *detect* that a screenshot or video recording of the whole or a part of the screen is being captured - regardless of the tool used (Gnome Screenshot, Shutter, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no, not on a vanilla Ubuntu distribution" (and btw, hitting printscreen is not the only way to take a screenshot).

The somewhat longer answer is that the question is ill-posed.  Whether some approach might work would depend on the specific combination of X server (or whatever display server you are using), window manager, whether you are willing to write your own X extensions, what your threat model is, how tight control you have of your environment, and so on.

I'm curious, though, what *is* your threat model?

Comment: There are several scenarios. Example 1: detect when users take screenshots of copyrighted content displayed inside a software I developed. Of course they can use their smartphones to take lower quality shots. Example 2: detect if an untrusted third-party software is spying on my desktop.